# Replicating this text in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

[image: Trade in and save]

Hi I am trying to replicate this text, i know the font is VAG Rounded, which i have, but i dont know which effects they applied to make the trade in and save part look the way they do.  I am new to photoshop and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't have Vag Rounded, but here is a quick mock up with Arial Rounded. While not 100% this took 2 minutes and should be a good starting point for you to adjust until it's perfect.

Just double click you text layer and add these styles.

[image: Example]
[image: Bevel]
[image: Stroke]
[image: Drop Shadow]

The red and blue text also have a slight gradient on them.

[image: Gradient]